# Puppeteer work well locally, but not in Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, puppeteer

I am try to scrap data from instagram and serve it in an api, So i use puppeteer and all things good locally but in heroku i get timeout

and that's the whole code, any one have a solution ?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");
const ig = require("instagram-url-dl");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const NodeCache = require("node-cache");
const myCache = new NodeCache({ stdTTL: 5 * 60 });
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const doc = fs.readFileSync("./doc.html", "utf-8");

let browser;
let page;

const lanuchBrowser = async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  page = await browser.newPage();
};
lanuchBrowser();

let url;

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(doc);
});

app.post("/download-reel", async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.writeHead(200);
  try {
    const { reel_url } = req.body;
    url = reel_url;
    const regex = /^https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/reel\//;
    const valid = regex.test(reel_url);
    if (!reel_url) {
      throw new Error("Missing parameter: reel_url");
    } else if (!valid) {
      throw new Error("Invalid parameter: reel_url");
    }

    // Caching
    const theRes = await myCache.get(reel_url);
    if (theRes) {
      return res.write(JSON.stringify(theRes));
    }
    res.write("");
    // Get download link
    const resp = await ig(reel_url);

    // Get author, title, timestamp
    await page.goto(reel_url, {
      timeout: 60000,
      waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
    });
    console.log("1");
    await page.waitForSelector("main", {
      timeout: 0,
    });
    console.log("2");
    const content = await page.content();
    console.log("3");
    let $ = cheerio.load(content);
    const author = $(
      "a.x1i10hfl.xjbqb8w.x6umtig.x1b1mbwd.xaqea5y.xav7gou.x9f619.x1ypdohk.xt0psk2.xe8uvvx.xdj266r.x11i5rnm.xat24cr.x1mh8g0r.xexx8yu.x4uap5.x18d9i69.xkhd6sd.x16tdsg8.x1hl2dhg.xggy1nq.x1a2a7pz._acan._acao._acat._acaw._aj1-._a6hd"
    ).text();
    $ = cheerio.load($("li._a9zj._a9zl._a9z5").html());
    console.log("4");
    const timestamp = $("time").attr("datetime");
    const title = $("h1._aacl._aaco._aacu._aacx._aad7._aade").text();

    let resObj = {
      sucess: true,
      download_link: resp.data[0].url,
      title,
      author,
      timestamp,
    };
    console.log("5");

    res.write(JSON.stringify(resObj));
    console.log("6");
    myCache.set(reel_url, resObj);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    err.message == "Missing parameter: reel_url"
      ? err.message
      : (err.message = "Invalid parameter: reel_url");
    res.write(
      JSON.stringify({
        sucess: false,
        error_message: err.message,
      })
    );
  } finally {
    res.end();
  }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("Lanuch the app ....");
});
```

I tried add {timeout: 0} i got no response from the server, So i tried to figure out where is the issue so i console.log number after each operation and when i run heroku logs --tail

I found out that only number 1 is print in the console

So the timeout happend wih this line of code

`await page.waitForSelector("main", { timeout: 0, });`

Comment: `{timeout: 0}` just turns clear errors into infinite hangs, making it harder to debug. Better to use `{timeout: 240_000}` or similar at the very most. If the action takes longer than that, it's almost certainly never going to succeed and you want an error report so you can diagnose the issue. Beyond that, I don't see how a timeout can occur as you claim with `{timeout: 0}`, which should never time out, unless Puppeteer is broken. What's `reel_url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uses this buildpack and it worked

https://github.com/jontewks/heroku-buildpack-puppeteer-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most probably here

```
 await page.goto(reel_url, {
      timeout: 60000,
      waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
    });
await page.waitForSelector("main", {
      timeout: 0,
    });
```

You can use `waitUntil:networkidle0` better than `domContentLoaded` to capture any lazy loaded requests in the page

`waitForSelector` will wait until the request times out so it isn't recommended to be used except in certain cases for lazy loaded selectors that are sure to be on the page.
instead you can do something like this:

```
const element = await page.$(selector)
if (element){
...your logic
}
```

This will try to find the selector after the page has loaded and network calls are finished, and if not found, it will move on and complete the rest of the request instead of hanging until timing out.
You can handle the case where the selector isn't present to log something or re-navigate to another page.

Comment: I get this error Error: Unknown value for options.waitUntil: networkIdle0

Comment: Sorry, I meant ```"networkidle0"```